# GRUB is now the default bootloader and i cant boot without a flashdrive with grub so i can select windows 7

Tags: 11.10, grub2, windows, bootloader

One night I installed ubuntu via live cd a couple times on different size flash-drives and grub is now the default bootloader. I used to could press the power button and it booted directly to windows 7, now I have to plug in a flash drive, boot from it and select windows 7 from the list. I want to get it back to the default where i can just press power and windows 7 will load.

I want to know how to boot directly into windows 7 without having that flash drive.

If you can help, please do.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a recovery disk for your version of windows. Once you have this you can boot to it and click the 'advanced repair' option (if it doesn't fix itself). Under 'Advanced Repair' you can select 'Recovery Console' and issue the following commands:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /rebuildBCD
```

This will wipe the MBR, the partition boot record, and install the default Windows bootloader. ***You will be unable to boot Ubuntu if you have it on your desktop***. Your USB drives will be unaffected and they will continue to work as expected.

Comment: Thank you lord, somebody can help me. And I am also thanking you @Huckle! It worked! I am the happiest person in the world right now! I had to create a system repair disc since I didn't have one. I am so glad I don't have to worry about losing that flashdrive now! Thank you!